# Import specific columns of a DataTable in Visual Basic

Tags: data-binding, datagridview, import

I have a DataTable with multiple columns in it, and i would like to import some of the columns with the data of every row of it to a DataGridView in VisualBasic.
Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very very generic. In either case here is a sample.

```
'Create a new datatable
      Dim table2 As New DataTable
      table2.Columns.Add("Name")

 'loop through your existing datatable - add the records to the columns you want
  For Each dr As DataRow In Table1.Rows
             Dim R As DataRow = dt.NewRow
             R("Name") = dr("TABLE1_COLUMNNAME")
             dt.Rows.Add(R)
  Next
 'turn the new datatable into the datagridview. 
 DataGridView1.DataSource = table2
```